# Parenthesis Expressions in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

If I want to generate the query `(month(created) = 1 and year(created) = 2010) or (month(modified) = 1 and year(modified) = 2010)` with linq, how would I go about it?

I have `o.Created.Value.Month == month && o.Created.Value.Year == year`. If I do `(o.Created.Value.Month == month && o.Created.Value.Year == year) || (o.Modified.Value.Month == month && o.Modified.Value.Year == year)` wouldn't the parenthesis just be ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the parentheses won't be ignored by LINQ - they're important to indicate the logic. They're *effectively* present in the expression tree, in that you'll end up with an "OR" expression with two subexpressions each of which is an "AND" expression.

The query you've given should be fine - have you tried it, and checked the resulting SQL?

Comment: Thanks, that did work (though used CONVERT instead of MONTH, but the results that are returned are still the same)